# Android Lollipop API 21 samples are missing?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

It looks like the Samples are missing for Android API 21 in the SDK downloader.

```
$ android list sdk --all | grep -i sample
  36- Samples for SDK API 20, revision 2
  37- Samples for SDK API 19, revision 6
  38- Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
  39- Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
  40- Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  41- Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  42- Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  43- Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  44- Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  45- Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  46- Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  47- Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  48- Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  49- Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
```

The bummer is that the Samples that were included with the Android-L preview are also missing now.

What is the URL to download either the Android Lollipop or Android-L-preview samples?  Or is there a way to do it in the SDK manager?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/ contains rather many Android-L samples. I'm not sure is it the same bundle that came with preview SDK though.

Comment: have you tried [the google developer portal](http://developer.android.com/samples/new/index.html) yet?

Comment: I agree that Samples are missing in the SDK Manager. And on the "What's new" page mentioned by @panini we can confirm that the most recent samples are for the L Developer Preview, which may suggest that the final samples are not ready yet.

Comment: They are available now (20-nov-14). Update your SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples are now available in the Android SDK.  Thanks to @dazzibao for the answer to this question.